# Audio Player Worked, Now it Doesn't

Tags: java, audio, audio-player

**I modified the audio player and posted a new (and not duplicate) question here: [BigClip Won't Play .wav File](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15911925/2255301)**

I wrote an audio player, and it worked, but now it doesn't. Here's the code:

```
package me.pogostick29.audiorpg.audio;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

public class AudioPlayer {

    private AudioPlayer() { }

    private static AudioPlayer instance = new AudioPlayer();

    public static AudioPlayer getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void play(String name) {
        AudioClip clip = null;
        try { clip = Applet.newAudioClip(new File("audio/" + name + ".wav").toURI().toURL()); }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        clip.play();
    }

    public void playDialogue(String character, String name) {
        play("people/" + character + "/" + name);
    }
}
```

However, when I try to play the audio file located here (http://icap.me/i/rNIXeCfScy.png)

using

```
AudioPlayer.getInstance().playDialogue("blacksmith", "blacksmith1");
```

from another class, it does nothing.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Absolutely nothing? As in no exceptions or errors?  Are you sure you have your speakers turned up?

Comment: I wrote a debug to print out when the audio clip started and when it ended. The start and end strings printed one right after the other.

Comment: Is this an applet or console based application?

Comment: It's console based. It uses a JFrame as its GUI and will not be embeded in a website.

Comment: I would recommend adding some logging, if possible, so you can provide a bit more description on the nature of the error

Comment: Use the [Java Sound](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) based `Clip` for this instead.  It gives useful feed-back when unable to load/parse a sound file.  The equivalent applet methods are designed to fail silently.

Comment: `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")`  **`@FixTheBloodyThingsRatherThanSuppressThem`**

Comment: *"However, when I try to play the audio file located here (http://icap.me/i/rNIXeCfScy.png)"*  `<HEAD-DESK/>`  It would be more useful to link to the `blacksmith1.wav` than a screenshot of your IDE showing the location on the local disks.

Comment: I tried using `getClass().getResource(...);`, but that didn't work. I was showing you where in the folder structure it was located, to make sure that I was referring to the right path.