# BigClip Won't Play .wav File

Tags: java, audio, javasound, audio-player

I am attempting to add an audio player to my application. Here's the code from the class that handles audio playing:

```
package me.pogostick29.audiorpg.audio;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine;

public class AudioPlayer {

    private AudioPlayer() { }

    private static AudioPlayer instance = new AudioPlayer();

    public static AudioPlayer getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private static ArrayList<BigClip> clips = new ArrayList<BigClip>();

    private BigClip get(String name) {
        for (BigClip clip : clips) {
            if (clip.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) return clip;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void play(File file) {
        try {
            AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
            BigClip clip = get(file.getName());
            if (clip == null) {
                BigClip newClip = new BigClip(file.getName());
                clips.add(newClip);
                clip = newClip;
            }
            clip.open(audioIn);
            clip.start();
        }
        catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

However, when I try to run it using:

```
AudioPlayer.getInstance().play(new File("audio/people/blacksmith/blacksmith01a_new.wav"));
```

I get the following stack trace:

```
javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input file
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1170)
    at me.pogostick29.audiorpg.audio.AudioPlayer.play(AudioPlayer.java:38)
    at me.pogostick29.audiorpg.person.people.Blacksmith.playDialogue(Blacksmith.java:12)
    at me.pogostick29.audiorpg.AudioRPG.main(AudioRPG.java:33)
```

[Here](http://icap.me/i/AkRHDOFsCW.png)'s the format I used when exporting the file with Audition.

Comment: Do this code and report the result.  `File f = new File("audio/people/blacksmith/blacksmith01a_new.wav"); System.out.println("File: " + f.exists());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I fixed it by using this library: http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: This question is 6 years old. Leave it alone.

Comment: Why should I leave it alone? If it is bad, it should go, if it is good, then leave it. This answer is bad and needs to go.